# How to do a Conditional Formatting with hh:mm:ss format on Excel

Tags: excel, timestamp, conditional-formatting

I have two different columns. Each one contains timestamps in `hh:mm:ss` format, and I want to do a `between` comparition and check if the Value Colum 2 is between Value Column 1 Row 1 and Value Column 1 Row 2, and then, paint the cell in green, or in red if the condition is not satisfied.

Here my columns:

```
Column 1     Column 2

16:06:13     16:07:34
16:06:41     16:08:42
16:08:39     16:09:49
16:09:47     16:11:02
16:10:53     16:12:10
16:12:08     16:13:40
16:13:39     16:14:48
16:14:47     16:16:04
16:18:06     16:18:06
```

I applied a `Conditional Formatting -> HighLight Cell Rules -> Between`

then from Column 2 Row 1, I selected the first value from Column 1 Row 1 and the next value from Column 1 Row 2, but nothing happens.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for your answers. All of them seems good and logic, but I tried all of them and Excel is doing nothing, I can't understand why... I tried 3 or 4 different rules applied to it and nothing happened

Comment: Before you give up, go to Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules and open the new rule and make sure that Excel saved the rule right. I've seen a bug where Excel replaces the cells you entered with the wrong ones, but if you edit it with the right ones it will stick.

Comment: Thank you @Trashman but I tried to do individual Conditional Formattings (I mean, Less for one hand and Greater for the other) instead of apply Between, because is the only way I get results. Thanks again for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the process you did:

1. Highlight the values in Column 2
2. Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> Between
3. Select the first value from Column 1 Row 1 **then delete the dollar signs**
4. Select the second value from Column 1 row 2 **then delete the dollar signs**

Note: I see that there is sometimes a glitch in some versions of Excel which replaces your cells with cells at the bottom of the spreadsheet. I find if I just repeat the steps another time, it fixes the issue.

Comment: I posted my answer before this one but it works good, upvote!

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, but even seems it has to work, Excel is doing nothing to my results, and I don't understand why. The cells are no filled with the specified color.

Comment: Solved. In the import data in to excel sheet, I introduced in a wrong way the data, missing a space between columns, so the hours had a space character in front so that's why it didn't work properly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Two rules with two different formulas:

1st:

```
=MEDIAN(B1,A1,A2)=B1
```

And format it to Green

2nd:

```
=MEDIAN(B1,A1,A2)<>B1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative method:

1. Highlight the values in column 2.
2. Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
3. Select "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Under "Format values where this formula is true", input: "=AND(B1 >= A1,B1 <= A2)"
5. Select "Format..." and choose the formatting you want
6. Click OK

Note that this method, vs. the other one I gave you, treats the last cell differently (since there's no value after it). The first one will highlight it, this one will not.

Note: With both methods, I see that there is sometimes a glitch where Excel replaces your cells (A1, A2, and B1 in this case) with cells at the bottom of the spreadsheet. I find if I just repeat the steps another time, it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stick with in-between you can

[image]

The data I have in those two fields is
    =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))
    =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN()-1))

You will still need two of these as said in other answers.